# PHP Find files with specific name part in folder

Tags: php, regex, file, elasticsearch, regex-lookarounds

Is there a way to get all the files with a specific name from a folder with php?
For example I have in folder next files:

6546-da6sd.png
465-dasd.jpg
654-548484.jpg
654-sasaf.png
654-sakj879.jpg
776-54fsdfs.png
....

I want to get all files that start with "654-" (but not the first (6546-da6sd.png))
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `glob()` and `strpos()` **like:**

```
<?php
$dir = 'files/';
$key = '654-';//search key
foreach (glob("$dir*") as $file) { 
    $file = str_replace($dir,'',$file);
    if (strpos($file, $key) == 0) {
        echo($file."<br>");
    }
}
?>
```